# How to disable alphabetical sorting page

Tags: child-pages

I'm using the following code to display child pages on their parent page and all child pages are sorting alphabetically.how i can turn it off or change sorting by creation date?

```
  <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'parent'      => $post->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
    $children = get_pages( $args );

    if ( ! empty( $children ) ) :
        ?>
        <div class="childcells"> 
            <?php
            foreach ( $children as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                ?>
                <div class="childcell">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small-thumb' ); ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="myclasstitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <span class="desc"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'desc', true ); ?></span>
                    <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <?php
            endforeach;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Use `orderby` and `order` in your query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Well i tried those, but still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) in the Code Reference you'll notice two parameters: `sort_order` and `sort_column`.

So, the following example will give you child pages list sorted by `menu_order`:

```
$pages = get_pages( array( 
    'child_of'    => $post->ID,
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'sort_order'  => 'desc',
) );
```

You can change menu order manually

[image]

or using a plugin, e. g. [Simple Page Ordering](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/).